# When using macvim with symlinks, is opening vim just calling mvim -v?

Tags: macvim, macos

I've installed macvim on OSX 10.11.6 using `brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim`. This worked fine. I now have some new aliases/symlinks (I'm not too familiar with the differences):

```
.
#in usr/local/bin
vim -> ../Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/bin/vim
mvim -> ../Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/bin/mvim
.
#in usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-119_1/bin/
vim -> mvim
mvim                                            #executable
```

`vim` opens vim in the terminal window (the updated version of vim, not OSX's). `mvim` opens macvim with its own window.

If vim is an alias for mvim, how does the machine know to run plain old vim when I type `vim`? Is it changing my command to `mvim -v` behind the scenes? If so, is this `-v` in the alias/symlink somewhere?

Any insight you all have be would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mvim` is a shell script which uses the name it's run as to decide what to do:

```sh
# Next, peek at the name used to invoke this script, and set options
# accordingly.

name="`basename "$0"`"
gui=
opts=

# GUI mode, implies forking
case "$name" in m*|g*|rm*|rg*) gui=true ;; esac
```

This is not uncommon. Vim itself reacts differently on whether it is invoked as `vim`, `vi`, `vimdiff`, `gvim`, etc.

So, running `mvim` as `vim` just runs `"$VIM_APP_DIR/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"` as it is, whereas running as `mvim` runs `"$VIM_APP_DIR/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim" -g`.

Also see:

- [Why does argv include the program name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315812/70524)

Comment: Ahh! So that's why `mvim` is so small? I never noticed it was only 2 kb, way too small to be the "main vim" getting launched. Thanks so much.